# Start two animation together

Tags: android, animation, kotlin

I want two start two animation together.

First animation is transaction animation

```
 val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left, R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right)
    transaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment, fragment::javaClass.name)
    transaction.addToBackStack(fragment::javaClass.name)
    transaction.commit()
```

And Second animation is seekbar animation in activity

```
abstract class BaseProgressFragment : BaseFragment() {

abstract val progressCount: Int

abstract val seekBar: NonEnabledSeekBar

abstract val tvProgress: TextView

override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    animateProgress()
}

private fun animateProgress() {
    val progress = "$progressCount%"
    val progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seekBar, "progress", seekBar.progress, progressCount * 100)
    progressAnimator.duration = 600
    progressAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
    progressAnimator.start()
    seekBar.progress = progressCount * 100
    tvProgress.text = progress
}}
```

In child fragment

```
override val seekBar: NonEnabledSeekBar
    get() = (activity as CreateOrderActivity).sbCreatingOrder
```

When i start only 1 animation thats okay, but when i try start they together UI start freeze.

Please tell me how I can solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can solved it that

```
seekBar.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, null)
```

and

```
val progressAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(seekBar, "progress", seekBar.progress, progressCount * 100)
        progressAnimator.duration = 600
        progressAnimator.interpolator = LinearInterpolator()
        progressAnimator.addListener(object : AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            override fun onAnimationEnd(animation: Animator) {
                seekBar.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_NONE, null)
            }
        })
        progressAnimator.start()
```